# Possible to navigate away from Careers profile edit page with unsaved form

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I was working on the personal statement in my Careers profile, and accidentally used a two-finger gesture to go back in history before saving it. When I went forward again, all my changes were gone.

Could we please have a warning? Or is there something that can be done with the History API that could just preserve the content without bugging us about it?

Comment: Yup, makes perfect sense. I would go one step forward and save a draft of this, like there are questions and answers drafts in all SE sites.

Comment: Thanks. I had meant to put this on Careers meta, but either I fired or a mod moved out here. I hope it ends up in the right place, either way.

Comment: Actually this is the proper Meta site for Careers, both for historical reasons and because Careers is on a different "plane" than Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: Gotcha. (Of course I meant "either I *goofed* or a mod moved *it* here.")